# Debugging jest from docker

Tags: docker, debugging, docker-compose, jestjs

I have a node project running in a docker container that chrome-debugger connects to via port 9229. When using the actual application (as opposed to running the test suite), debugger shows errors/break points just fine.

However, when I run `npm run test:e2e` from within the docker container, debugger commands, break points, etc are completely ignored. The test suite runs, but it doesn't pick up any breaks.

Admittedly I'm new to both docker & node, but the fact that the app (as opposed to jest) break points are working has me thoroughly confused. If anyone has any ideas on how to get jest break points from a docker container working in chrome-debugger (or vs code for that matter), I'd be really appreciative. Config details below:

## docker-compose.yml

```
pf_debugger:
  build: ./pf
  image: pf_debugger
  container_name: pf_debugger
  working_dir: /www
  ports:
    - "9229:9229"
  command: "npm run start:debug"
  volumes:
   - ./pf:/www
   - node_modules:/www/node_modules
  depends_on:
    - "indy_pool"
    - "pf"
  networks:
    - pf_network
```

## package.json

```
# ...
"scripts":
  "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",        
  "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
```

## jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

## nodemon-debug.json

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "inspect": "0.0.0.0:9229",
  "exec": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --debug -r ts-node/register src/main.ts"
}
```

## launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
       "type": "node",
       "request": "attach",
       "name": "Node: Nodemon",
       "restart": true,
       "sourceMaps": true,
       "protocol": "inspector",
       "address": "127.0.0.1",
       "port": 9229,
       "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
       "remoteRoot": "/www/"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "e2e-tests",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "args": [
        "--runInBand",
        "--config=test/jest-e2e.json"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: when you run tests locally with vscode, do you get jest breakpoints correctly?

Comment: Yes - running locally, breakpoints show up just fine

Comment: did you try to connect visual studio to a remote debugger?

Comment: @Tree Yes. I added launch.json above for clarity. :-)

Comment: I am not the expert as well, but could it be that you are exposing debugger to localhost, and when you want to connect to it from external debugger, it needs to be exposed to some external interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, I solved my own problem. Appending `--runInBand` to the `npm:test` command ensures breakpoints are obeyed

Comment: but where is your npm:test in those configs you wrote? could you explain better? I'm with the same problems... /\

Comment: Hello PlankTon, can you post your complete solution? I'm with this issue here too.